# Cloud Firestore - Two Player - Detect disconnection [Flutter]

Tags: socket.io, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
    DocumentSnapshot roomSnapshot = await tx.get(_docRef);
    if (roomSnapshot.exists) {
      await tx.update(_docRef, {
        'isAvailable': false, //change room status to unavailable.
      });
```

I am making two player non-graphical game using flutter. 
Firestore is easy and scalable. So i decided to use it.

How do i detect the disconnection of one of the user?

```
_roomCollectionRef.document(documentId).snapshots().listen((onData) {
```

Here i am listening on the room and streaming the scores.

Or should i use sockets.io's dart plugin for such a use-case?

Comment: After reading the answer, it seems there is no option detecting the disconnection in firestore. it is really bad news!

Comment: Why do you not just create a field in Firestore that shows last connection time and check against that on the other client?

Comment: It is just a 30 seconds game. For that i have to make lot of read and write which will increase the firestore cost :-(